# get_intermediate_image_sizes Get the Size Names but How Do I Get the Sizes?

Tags: images, widgets

I'm setting up a widget that allows to add an image to a sidebar / widget area.

Basically I have a dropdown that allows the user to select one of the available sizes inside the theme's `functions.php` file using `add_image_size()`.

Apart from the obvious ( renaming all the `add_image_size()` ) is there a way to get the size so that I can display that as well as the name?

This is my current drop down code:

```
<?php       
    $sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();
    $available_size  = '<select name="' . $this->get_field_name('image') . '" >' . "\r\n";
    $available_size .= '<option value="0" selected="selected">Choose</option>' . "\r\n";
    foreach ( $sizes as $size ) {
        if ( $instance['size'] == $size ) :
            $available_size .= '<option value="' . $size . '" selected="selected">' . $size . '</option>' . "\r\n";
        else :
            $available_size .= '<option value="' . $size . '">' . $size . '</option>' . "\r\n";         
        endif;
    }

    $available_size .= '</select>' . "\r\n";

    echo $available_size;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;
print '<pre>';
print_r( $_wp_additional_image_sizes );
print '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

**Get all possible registered image size with their names**

```php
$wp_additional_image_sizes = wp_get_additional_image_sizes();

$sizes = array();
$get_intermediate_image_sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();

// Create the full array with sizes and crop info
foreach ($get_intermediate_image_sizes as $_size) {
  if (in_array($_size, array('thumbnail', 'medium', 'large'))) {
    $sizes[$_size]['width'] = get_option($_size . '_size_w');
    $sizes[$_size]['height'] = get_option($_size . '_size_h');
    $sizes[$_size]['crop'] = (bool) get_option($_size . '_crop');
  } elseif (isset($wp_additional_image_sizes[$_size])) {
    $sizes[$_size] = array(
      'width' => $wp_additional_image_sizes[$_size]['width'],
      'height' => $wp_additional_image_sizes[$_size]['height'],
      'crop' =>  $wp_additional_image_sizes[$_size]['crop']
    );
  }
}
foreach ($sizes as $key => $image_size) {
  echo  "<li> ⚡ {$key} ☛ ({$image_size['width']} x {$image_size['height']}) {$image_size['crop']} </li>";
}
```