# How to get a list of all the possible thumbnail sizes set within a theme

Tags: images

What function can I use in a plugin to get the dimensions of every image size (in an array preferably) that is defined in a child theme?

Just for clarification I am not asking how to *create* a new image size.

Comment: Searching for something like this, but with an interface, came across the plugin [Additional image sizes (zui)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/additional-image-sizes-zui/). It has 500 days without updates but passed the first batch of tests.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[Found it here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16143/get-intermediate-image-sizes-get-the-size-names-but-how-do-i-get-the-sizes). The answer is:

```
global $_wp_additional_image_sizes; 
print '<pre>'; 
print_r( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ); 
print '</pre>';
```

Comment: Adding it to the top of the `functions.php` file won't work, but stick it in any of your functions in that file and it should work.

Comment: This lists only the additional sizes, not sizes like "large"

Comment: Wrong answer, should not be accepted as such.

Comment: As of 2023 this is the correct answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33532/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-the-possible-thumbnail-sizes-set-within-a-theme#answer-410707

Answer (score 35):

WordPress core [doesn't have a native method](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/06/24/image-sizes-in-wordpress) for getting intermediate image sizes (i.e. width and height), but the [following helper function](https://gist.github.com/eduardozulian/6467854) will get all registered image sizes along with their dimensions:

```php
/**
 * Get all the registered image sizes along with their dimensions
 *
 * @global array $_wp_additional_image_sizes
 *
 * @link http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18947 Reference ticket
 *
 * @return array $image_sizes The image sizes
 */
function _get_all_image_sizes() {
    global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;

    $default_image_sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();

    foreach ( $default_image_sizes as $size ) {
        $image_sizes[ $size ][ 'width' ] = intval( get_option( "{$size}_size_w" ) );
        $image_sizes[ $size ][ 'height' ] = intval( get_option( "{$size}_size_h" ) );
        $image_sizes[ $size ][ 'crop' ] = get_option( "{$size}_crop" ) ? get_option( "{$size}_crop" ) : false;
    }

    if ( isset( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ) && count( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ) ) {
        $image_sizes = array_merge( $image_sizes, $_wp_additional_image_sizes );
    }

    return $image_sizes;
}
```

Which will output results similar to:

```
Array
(
    [thumbnail] => Array
        (
            [width] => 150
            [height] => 150
            [crop] => 1
        )

    [medium] => Array
        (
            [width] => 300
            [height] => 300
            [crop] => 
        )

    [medium_large] => Array
        (
            [width] => 768
            [height] => 0
            [crop] => 
        )

    [large] => Array
        (
            [width] => 1024
            [height] => 1024
            [crop] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: +1 for a more complete answer. The others return additional sizes but not default ones.

Comment: Even better if you use `$default_image_sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();` as there's a `medium_large` size since WP 4.4.

Comment: Good suggestion; I've updated the answer with your recommendation.

Comment: ACF has spoiled me with its media array.

Comment: Useful in WP 5.4 using PHP 7.3 on March 2020 :)

Comment: Since 5.3, there is wp_get_registered_image_subsizes()

Comment: This answer works like a charm, but is superseded by the last comment, for Wordpress 5.3 and up: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_registered_image_subsizes/

Answer (score 18):

If you only need the names of all image sizes, you can use [get_intermediate_image_sizes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_intermediate_image_sizes):

```
<pre>
<?php print_r(get_intermediate_image_sizes()); ?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 16):

Since WP 5.3 it is enough to use this function:

```
wp_get_registered_image_subsizes();
```

Documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_registered_image_subsizes/

Comment: The shortest and the only correct answer here, but why so low in rankings.

Comment: The only proper answer. Probably low ranking because it is only around since WP 5.3, which at the time of the OP question was not around.
Yet, this should be the only accepted answer, as everything else is the usual "throw in some code SO trash" - upvoted to get it up.

Answer (score 5):

If the other answer did not work, use this code, so it will run after WordPress is initialized.

```
add_action('init', 'get_all_image_sizes');

function get_all_image_sizes(){
    global $_wp_additional_image_sizes; 
    print '<pre>'; 
    print_r( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ); 
    print '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: I have tested several methods and this one finally worked. (WP + WooCommerce + custom theme)

Answer (score 4):

Since WP 4.7 you can use [wp_get_additional_image_sizes()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_additional_image_sizes/) to get additional image sizes registered (excluding the default image sizes added by WP).

Since WP 5.3 you can use [wp_get_registered_image_subsizes()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_registered_image_subsizes/) to get all the image sizes registered.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following functions:

```
get_intermediate_image_sizes(); // get all the image size names.
wp_get_additional_image_sizes(); // get all the additional image size data.
wp_get_registered_image_subsizes(); // get all the image size data.
```